# Валидация данных в SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

- Я пытаюсь добавить CREATE VIEW, чтобы можно было посмотреть список посетителей и их данные, но получаю данную ошибку:

```
CREATE VIEW [People attended] AS
SELECT visitorName, visitorNum
FROM visitor;
```

В чем может быть проблема? Я ввожу его в самом конце скрипта

> "Incorrect syntax: 'CREATE VIEW' must be the only statement in the
> batch."

- Хочу ввести данные регистрации и использовать TRANSACTION, чтобы проверить делал ли регистрацию пользователь до этго, чтобы предотвратить double entry

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Booking(bookingID, visitorNum, tableID, visitorID, reservationTime, startTime, endTime)
    VALUES ('1','4', '1', '2','16.00','18.00','20.00')
    CONSTRAINT no_double_entry CHECK
```

Как его правильно сформулировать?

Мой код доступен по ссылке: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6182b

Comment: Вам необходимо использовать оператор `GO` между разными операторами SQL в batch.

Comment: По-моему, Вы что-то путаете. Попытка создания вьюва должна выдать ошибку: *Msg 111 Level 15 State 1 Line 51
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.* Что означает, что GO следует поместить непосредственно перед CREATE VIEW.

Comment: На фидл вроде как ошибку не выдает а тоько в azure. Но кажется разобрался. Теперь не могу понять как сформулировать запрос с transaction